# AngularJS D3. How to append anything to existing graph (draw over it)?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, svg

All examples online seem to be with using

```
    d3.select("body").append("div") etc.
```

How to append something to graph that already exists? I assume this will be a directive like this?

```
.controller(....)
.directive('myNodes', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var nodes = [{"name": "foo"}, {"name": "bar"}];
            var mySvg = d3.select(element[0])
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", 100)
            .attr("height", 100);

            mySvg.append("line")
            .style("stroke", "green")
            .attr("x1", 1)
            .attr("y1", 1)
            .attr("x2", 40)
            .attr("y2", 50);

            element.removeAttr("my-nodes");
            $compile(element)(scope);
        }
      };
  }]);
```

but all examples I've found add another svg, and I cannot select existing one

Fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/shuxerezad/8kzesguo/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to append a line to already drawn svg

Your case you are appending/creating the svg to the element:

```
var mySvg = d3.select(element[0])
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", 100)
            .attr("height", 100);
```

To append to already drawn svg do:

```
 var mySvg = d3.select(element[0]).select("svg");//get the svg already drawn there
```

Now since you are using angular directive the above mySVG may come null reason is that the nvd3 draws the graph later and the time when your line is drawn the *d3.select(element[0]).select("svg")* will have no svg.

Thus, you will need to trigger your directive link function after a delay so that the svg is drawn and the graph is ready.

```
link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var doRender = function () {
                var nodes = [{
                    "name": "foo"
                }, {
                    "name": "bar"
                }];
                var mySvg = d3.select(element[0]).select("svg");

                mySvg.append("line")
                    .style("stroke", "green")
                    .attr("x1", 1)
                    .attr("y1", 1)
                    .attr("x2", 400)
                    .attr("y2", 50);
                // Make sure that $compile doesn't recompile
                // the directive and remove the d3 nodes
                element.removeAttr("my-nodes");
                $compile(element)(scope);
            }
            setTimeout(doRender, 3000);//so that the line is drawn when the svg is present...execute doRender after 3 secs
        }
```

Full working code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/0qckrscu/2/)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! it helps to understand basics sometimes)